# Parsing input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have a table for a school card.The aim is to display the average per grading period.The data is from the database while the average result is from the javascript.When a user input in any of the input fields, the average along that column should dynamically changes or update it.Now in my current code,It generates an error e.text() is not a function.Basically the sum variable didn't catch a value from the parseInt.Anyone have an idea resolving this issue?

****** sample results******

```
    Subject | Col1 |Col2 |Col3 |Col4
    1          80    80   86    80       (80+80+86+80)/4  Note: not this way
    2          86    85   86    81
    3          80    87   85    86

  Result       82    84  and so on..
    It should be:
    (80+86+80)/3 number of rows
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="3">Subjects</th>
     <th colspan="2">First Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Second Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Third Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Fourth Grading</th>

 </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
      @foreach($update_card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
       {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
<tr>
<td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td> 
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="{!! $subject->term_1 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="{!! $subject->term_2 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="{!! $subject->term_3 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="{!! $subject->term_4 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>
 <td class="ave" value="0"></td>
</tr>
         @endforeach

<tr id="average">
 <td colspan="3">Average</td><td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**javascript here**

```
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
         $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
              var sum = 0; // The summation of all terms.
              var card = 0; // Number of cells.
              $(this).children('td').not(':first').each(function(i, e) {
                  card++;
                  sum+= parseInt(e.text().trim()); //this is the error
              });
              var avg = sum/card;
              console.log(avg);
              $("#average td:nth-of-type("+index+")").html(avg);
        });
});
```

Comment: Chee, you are taking value from td's text but you value resides in input filed which is inside td, so here's what you should do:

sum+= parseInt($(e).find("input").val()); //this is the error

Comment: what sum1 says, or `$(this).children('input')...`

Comment: I tried to debug,another problem is that  its not calculating according to column.The aim here is to add all the values under First grading then get the sum and average same as the rest of the grading.

Comment: use `e.val()` insead of `e.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *as I pointed*  you loop through `tds` and get `text()` while it has no text on it .. it
>   has an input so you need to get the input value not the td text

so you can try something like this

I create a functions for `row_sum()` to sum the row ,`column_sum()` to sum the column ,`column_Average()` to get column average by row numbers and `row_Average()` to get row average by td numbers.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("keyup", function() {
     //row_sum();      // for sum row
     //column_sum();   // for sum column
     column_Average(); // for column average
     row_Average();    // for row average
  }).keyup();  // by adding .keyup() your code will run onload
});



function column_sum(){
  var sum = []; // The summation of all terms.
  $("tbody tr:not(#average)").each(function(index) {
    var thisIt = $(this);
      thisIt.find('td:not(.ave)').not(':first').each(function(i) {
        var input_val = ($.trim($(this).find('input').val())) ? $(this).find('input').val().trim() : 0;
        sum[i] ? sum[i] += parseInt(input_val) : sum.push(parseInt(input_val));
    });  
  });
  $('#average td:not(:first)').each(function(i){
    $(this).text(sum[i]);
  });
}
function row_sum(){
  $("tbody tr:not(#average)").each(function(index) {
    var thisIt = $(this);
    var sum = 0; // The summation of all terms.
    thisIt.find('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i) {
          var input_val = ($.trim($(this).find('input').val())) ? $(this).find('input').val().trim() : 0;
          sum += parseInt(input_val); 
    });
  thisIt.find('td.ave').text(sum);
  });
}

function column_Average(){
  var sum = []; // The summation of all terms.
  var tr_num = $("tbody tr:not(#average)").length;
  $("tbody tr:not(#average)").each(function(index) {
    var thisIt = $(this);
      thisIt.find('td:not(.ave)').not(':first').each(function(i) {
        var input_val = ($.trim($(this).find('input').val())) ? $(this).find('input').val().trim() : 0;
        sum[i] ? sum[i] += parseInt(input_val) : sum.push(parseInt(input_val));
    });  
  });
  $('#average td:not(:first)').each(function(i){
    $(this).text(sum[i] / tr_num);
  });
}


function row_Average(){
  $("tbody tr:not(#average)").each(function(index) {
    var thisIt = $(this);
    var sum = 0; // The summation of all terms.
     var code = 0;  thisIt.find('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i) {
          var input_val = ($.trim($(this).find('input').val())) ? $(this).find('input').val().trim() : 0;
          code++;
          sum += parseInt(input_val); 
    });
  thisIt.find('td.ave').text(sum / code);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>   
<tr>
   <th colspan="3">Subjects</th>
     <th colspan="2">First Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Second Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Third Grading</th>
     <th colspan="2">Fourth Grading</th>
     <th>Average</th>
 </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Subject</td> 
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="12" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="13" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="14" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="15" class="form-control number-only"></td>
 <td class="ave" value="0"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">Subject</td> 
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="120" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="130" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="140" class="form-control number-only"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="150" class="form-control number-only"></td>
 <td class="ave" value="0"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="average">
 <td colspan="3">Average</td><td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td> <td colspan="2">0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This very useful and complete.Good example and i think i can manage to manipulate few things because I decided not to include the last column Average.I only need the average.The important thing is the average at the bottom.Thank you so much for sharing your great knowledge in this field of expertise Mr Mohamed.

Comment: @Chee You're totally welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Same to you Sir.